# (PHP) Converting an array of arrays from one format into another

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently have an array, created from a database, an example of which looks like the following:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array (
        objectid => 2,
        name => title,
        value => apple
    ),

    [1] => Array (
        objectid => 2,
        name => colour,
        value => red
    ),

    [2] => Array (
        objectid => 3,
        name => title,
        value => pear
    ),

    [3] => Array (
        objectid => 3,
        name => colour,
        value => green
    )
)
```

What I would like to do is group all the items in the array by their objectid, and convert the 'name' values into keys and 'value' values into values of an associative array....like below:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        objectid => 2,
        title => apple,
        colour => red
    ),

    [1] => Array (
        objectid => 3,
        title => pear,
        colour => green
    )
)
```

I've tried a few things but haven't really got anywhere.. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with your current setup and should be able to handle as many key-value pairs as available:

```
<?php

$results = array(
    array('objectid' => 2, 'name' => 'title', 'value' => 'apple'), 
    array('objectid' => 2, 'name' => 'color', 'value' => 'red'),
    array('objectid' => 3, 'name' => 'title', 'value' => 'pear'), 
    array('objectid' => 3, 'name' => 'color', 'value' => 'green'));

$final = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $final[$result['objectid']]['objectid'] = $result['objectid'];
    $final[$result['objectid']][$result['name']] = $result['value'];
}

print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to have the array keys correspond with your object id, that way you can iterate through your existing array, and add the key-value pairs for each object, like so:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {

    if (!array_key_exists($result['objectid'], $newArray)) {
        $newArray[$result['objectid'] = array();
    }

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[$result['objectid'][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Peter's method is perfectly valid, I just thought I would show a shorter version of the same thing (couldn't do in a comment)

```
foreach( $array as $obj ) {
    if( !isset( $objects[$obj['objectid']] ) )
        $objects[$obj['objectid']]['objectid'] = $obj['objectid'];

    $objects[$obj['objectid']][$obj['name']] = $obj['value'];
}
```